# How to fix Containers/Body Width of one page website (html, css and js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, width, containers

Please see the screenshot below of my one page website i am trying to create.

Issue - Width of body (shown as selected in picture below)

[image]

I want to increase the width of whole website so that the two titles ("Hobbies and Interests" and "Contact Me") can be accommodated in the 2nd line along with the 2 titles(Recognition's and Appreciations and Extramural Engagements and Accolades)

please refer below image for how i want it to look.
[image]

I got this by making changes using F12.

However, when i try to change the same thing in skel-noscript.css as below, it doesn't work.

/* Container */

```
body {
    width: 1400px;
}

.container {
    width: 1400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try adding max-width: none; for .container class

Comment: Perhaps your browser is caching the stylesheet, so it is not refreshing. For example in Chrome, you can right click the refresh button with the Dev Tools open and click `Hard Reload`. I'm sure there is a way to do it for most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It will be usefull if you will also post here your `HTML` code

Anyway have you already try this:

```
.container {
    width: 1400px;
    margin:0 auto;
 }
```